# UITapGeatureRecogniser is not working on 2 labels

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to use two `TapGestures` on two labels, but it always shows the result of last one TapGesture. My code is as follows:

```
 [write_review_label addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(open_view:)]];
[map_image addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(open_view:)]];
write_review_label.tag = 1;
map_image.tag = 2;

-(void)open_view:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recog1
{
NSLog( @"recog1.view.tag == %d",recog1.view.tag);
if (recog1.view.tag==2)
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mapsegue" sender:self];
}
else
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginsegue" sender:self];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default User interaction is disable for label and imageview,

make it enabled.

```
[write_review_label setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];   
[map_image setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable user interaction of labels like:

```
write_review_label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
map_image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```